# Hover only Once

Tags: css, hover

Is there anyway that I can get my CSS only to go through the hover cycle once?

I need to keep the CSS intact and ADD a solution rather than completely changing it.

This maybe impossible, but I thought I'd ask.

CSS:

```
html .sensitive10, .sensitive5, .sensitive75, .sensitive15, .dp{
 opacity: 1.0;
-webkit-transition: 5s all ease-in-out;   
-webkit-transition-delay: 60s; 
}

html:hover .dp{
 opacity: 0.0;
 -webkit-transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition-delay: 16s;
}

#box{
 height: 60px;
 width: 60px;
 background: #0DF;
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div id="box" class="dp"></div>
 <body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: It's definitely impossible for us to help you without your code.

Comment: It's possible with javascript.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried

Comment: Please explain what your is intended to accomplish, what results you're getting, and how they differ from the desired results.

Comment: Okay guys, he added his code, so stop downvoting. This is a perfectly reasonable programming question with, or without any code. "How can I have a CSS hover that only functions once".

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with jQuery .one() function, here is the reference:

http://api.jquery.com/one/

And the relevant example:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="count">0</div>
<div class="target">Hover me</div>

<script>
  var n = 0;
  $(".target").one("mouseenter", function() {
    $(".count").html(++n);
  });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Code Added, Thanks for your help so far :D

Answer (score 1):

What you need is an `onmouseout` with a javascript function that would change your element's `className` to a css class that would not have a `hover` defined.

**CSS**

```
.element_with_hover{(...)}
.element_with_hover:hover{(...)}
.element_without_hover{(...)}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="element_with_hover" id="hoverMe" onmouseout="javascript:removeHover('hoverMe');"></div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function removeHover(elementId){
    document.getElementById(elementId).className = "element_without_hover";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with CSS now by using CSS Animation that will work only once on hover.

E.g.

```
@keyframes hideOpacity{
    from {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

then use it on your class's hover

```
html:hover .dp{
 animation-name: swipeHover;
 animation-duration: 2s;
}
```